# New Relic monitoring for "DB2 on Cloud" database

Tags: db2, newrelic

How to setup New Relic monitoring for "DB2 on Cloud" database instance or point me to the documentation?

Answer (score -1):

You should refer to newrelic for any detailed configuration questions.

newrelic publishes some information about their java agent and jdbc driver support on their website at https://docs.newrelic.com

newrelic also published some information on their Datastore API.

See https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/relic-solution-understanding-the-datastore-api-an-example-use-case/68382

See also https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/api-guides/java-agent-api-instrument-external-calls-messaging-datastore-web-frameworks/#datastore-api

If you seek contacts for a reference site, you should discuss with newrelic.